# Ошибка при обращении к JSON

Tags: angularjs

Добрый день! Имеется JSON файл с данными. Пытаюсь получить данные из JSON файла, консоль ошибок выдает:

Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$http.get')

Пример JSON:

```
{

  "variantA": {
    "sumInsuredThirty": [
      {
        "DAYFROM": 1,
        "DAYTO": 3,
        "TARIF": 2
      },
      {
        "DAYFROM": 4,
        "DAYTO": 5,
        "TARIF": 2
      },
      {
        "DAYFROM": 6,
        "DAYTO": 8,
        "TARIF": 4
      }
}
```

Вот так получаю данные из JSON:

```
$http.get('/JSON/rates.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.rates = data;

        });
```

Подскажите, в чем ошибка? Файл JSON проверку на валидность проходит.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: пропущены закрывающие "]" и "}"

Comment: @Igor, закрывающие "]" и "}" в исходнике есть. Это просто кусок для примера. JSON проходит проверку на валидность. Синтаксис верен.

Comment: Ошибка вот - `Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$http.get')`

Answer (score 2):

> Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$http.get')

Вы не заинжектили/некорректно заинжектили сервис `$http`, он у вас `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

Посмотрите содержимое data, который возвращает сервис `$http`. Должно быть следующее:

```
$http.get('/JSON/rates.json').success(function(data) {
  $scope.rates = data.data;
});
```